# SQL server 2012 select issues

Tags: sql-server, select

I have a database called X. In this DB I have two tables A and B. Table A have 89 rows, table b have 49. When I peform two independent SELECT's result ir correct, but when i mix and try to peform one select for both tables I'm getting back some mysterious number of rows.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM A (89 rows, that's correct)
SELECT * FROM B (49 rows, that's correct)

SELECT * FROM A, B (4361 rows, and information there is repeating and duplicating)
```

Thanks!

Comment: This similar to a JOINING on no condition `FROM A JOIN B ON 1 = 1`.

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to achieve

Comment: In one table I have installed software in pc, in other pc updates. And I want to get info from both tables. Tables don't have equal number of rows.

Comment: Presumably you have a common identifier for PC in both tables - you should join the 2 tables on that column

Answer (score 1):

I think you're actually looking for

```
SELECT * FROM A
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM B
```

I think you want the results of both tables in one result set, and the way of doing that is to use UNION between the SELECT statements.

Mind you, this will only work if the columns in A and B are identical, in terms of datatype and in the table's definition.

**The datatype of column #1 from table A will have to be the same as the datatype of column #1 from table B and so on.** (this is valid only if you use `SELECT *`)

You can also specify the columns so the datatypes match, in order.

```
SELECT col1, col3, col2 from A
UNION ALL
SELECT col2, col1, col3 from B
```

(if col1 from A has the same datatype as col2 from B etc.)

Comment: Hm, i tried, but there is another problem. I'm getting error about equal number of expressions but table A have 89 rows and B have 49. And when I peform select I want to get 138 rows with info from both tables.

Comment: @user22401 Ensure that when using the UNION statement that each SELECT has the same number of columns and of the right type. See Radu's second answer above.

Answer (score 0):

What your last query is doing is performing CARTESIAN PRODUCT .

**89 rows from TableA multiplied by 49 rows from TableB = 4361 rows in result**

Comment: Yes, just checked. Hmm, is there a option to get correct number of rows?

Comment: that depends on what do you want from both the tables..plz specify

Comment: In one table I have installed software in pc, in other pc updates. And I want to get info from both tables.

Comment: post both the table structure

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select by **CARTESIAN PRODUCT .**

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM A 
UNION ALL       // It will select all 89 + 49 records from both table
SELECT * FROM B
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM A 
UNION          // It will select all records from both table without duplicate
SELECT * FROM B
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you have used is the equivalent of doing a CROSS JOIN - ie it combines all rows from both tables - this returns all combinations of rows between your 2 tables - which in this case is 49 * 89.

Can you clarify what data you are expecting to return?

Comment: In one table I have installed software in pc, in other pc updates. I'm creating it for further use in reportin services. Now I'm stuck with it.

Comment: It's hard to say without more details, but I would have thought you need to use an INNER JOIN between your 2 tables based on one or more key columns